# Getting @attributes from JSON using php

Tags: php, json

I need to get the  @attribute value from json  using php.

I need  to get toatal,surchargetotal,nightlyRateTotal,maxNightlyRate values using php .

How can I get the value using php ?

How can I get total amount 335.72 using php ?

```
                                [RateInfo] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [@rateChange] => false
                                        [@promo] => true
                                        [@priceBreakdown] => true


                                        [ChargeableRateInfo] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [@total] => 335.72
                                                [@surchargeTotal] => 44.42
                                                [@nightlyRateTotal] => 291.3
                                                [@maxNightlyRate] => 145.65
                                                [@currencyCode] => USD
                                                [@commissionableUsdTotal] => 291.3
                                                [@averageRate] => 145.65
                                                [@averageBaseRate] => 171.35



                                            )

                                    )
```

Comment: Maybe show the JSON?  This is a dump of part of something.

Comment: [*What have you tried?*](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What are the issues with your current implementation?

Comment: Post more of your code, what you have tried, and what's wrong with your current code

Comment: how can i get total amount 335.72 using php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can typecast it to an array:

```php
$array = (array)$object;
echo $array['ChargeableRateInfo']['@surchargetotal'];
```

you can encode to JSON then decode again as an associative array

```php
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
echo $array['ChargeableRateInfo']['@surchargetotal'];
```

Since you provided no other info, thats my best guess.

Comment: $array = (array)$object;
echo $array['ChargeableRateInfo']['@surchargetotal']; this helped me .now i can take as echo $array['ChargeableRateInfo']['@surchargetotal']; thanks mate

Comment: click the "accept answer" icon below the "downvote" button at the left then ;)

Comment: to get the @attribute value from json using php you need to encapsulate key between {}. Like that: `RateInfo->ChargeableRateInfo->{"@surchargeTotal"}`